# How to vertically center *injected* div in HTML smoothly?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a div which is perfectly centered courtesy flex. Now I inject some content dynamically into the centered div. It remains *centered* of course, but it *jerks* into that centered position, which looks downright *ugly*.

Is there anyway to make the centering smooth? I tried setting `transition: all` but it has no effect.

Here is a fiddle for reference and quick testing: http://jsfiddle.net/qv8fLu4n/

Comment: When you remove the `injected-content` the `h1` moves vertically down the y-axis? Is that what you mean by `jerks`?

Comment: @Quoid to remain centered, the whole outer div “center-me” moves. That moving is not smooth, which is what I call “jerky”.

Comment: ok, got ya. Just so you know, if Safari, **Center me plz** does not move when removing the `injected--content` - I am on Safari 8.

Comment: @Quoid I’m on Safari 9.0 and it moves for me, which is the intended behaviour. You should try a more modern browser maybe? I haven’t prefixed flex with the browser specific properties.

Comment: I still consider Safari 8 modern; I have 9 on my other machines, just pointing out that your methods do not work on a relatively new browser, which could beneficial to your approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that on page load you grab the height of the element you want to shrink, set that as the `max-height` of the element, and then toggle the `max-height` property between `0px` and `initial height of element`.  For example:

```
var i = document.querySelector(".injected-block");
var maxHeight = i.clientHeight + 'px';
i.style.maxHeight = maxHeight;

document.getElementById("injection-button").onclick = (function () {
    if (i.style.maxHeight === '0px') {
        i.style.maxHeight = maxHeight;
    } else {
        i.style.maxHeight = 0;
    }
});
```

The animation can then be handled with a `transition: max-height` on the disappearing element, e.g.

```
.injected-block {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s;
}
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qv8fLu4n/3/)

### **EDIT**

Since the goal is to start with the element being invisible, you'll have to resort to some hacky stuff.  Here's a function that will take the invisible element, stick it in an off-screen div, and return the height of it.

```
var getHeight = function(el) {
    var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById('hidden');
    var clone = el.cloneNode(true);
    clone.className = '';
    clone.style.width = el.clientWidth + 'px';

    hiddenDiv.appendChild(clone);
    var height = clone.clientHeight + 'px';
    hiddenDiv.removeChild(clone);

    return height;
};
```

So you'd use it like:

```
var i = document.querySelector(".injected-block");
var maxHeight = getHeight(i);
i.style.maxHeight = 0;
```

This uses a div `#invisible`.  Example CSS (would need to be adapted for your situation) for this is:

```
#hidden {
    position: fixed;
    top: -1000px;
    left: -1000px;
}
```

And here's another [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qv8fLu4n/5/).  Cheers!

Comment: Yep this would work, but how would I get the height of the element before I inject it?

Comment: @Dizzy in reverse you *could* add an arbitrary `max-height` value, something you know will be greater than needed, since `max-height` won't fill unneeded space

Comment: @Dizzy I used a similar method in my answer but grabbed the height (rather than max-height) programmatically using `window.getComputedStyle(i, null).getPropertyValue("height")`

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I was playing off your example fiddle where the injected div defaults to being visible.  At that point, you'd have to resort to some hacky stuff, like cloning the element, sticking it in an off-screen div, and grabbing the height.  I'll post another fiddle in a sec.

Comment: @bowheart I'm curious about the off canvas element you did in your edit; since you were using  `max-height` as the transition property, wouldn't it be easier just to add an arbitrary number there rather than creating a *'ghost'* element to keep off canvas, since `max-height` only uses necessary available space (considering the user will have the content hidden first and *then* show it)? - ps: I totally agree your approach is the best solution, just continuing the conversation

Comment: @Quoid putting a transition on a `max-height` property tells the browser, "Take this long to get the height from point x (`0px`) to point y (your 'arbitrary number')".  In other words, if I have an element whose height is `100px`, and--just to be safe--I set it's arbitrary `max-height` to `500px`, and I say `transition: max-height 0.5s;`, the visible animation (from `0px` to `100px`) will be completed in 0.1 seconds--the other 0.4 seconds being used to animate the `max-height` from `100px` to `500px`.  Moving the other way, this results in a 0.4s delay before the element starts animating.

Comment: @Quoid In short, setting arbitrary numbers as the `max-height` leads to erratic and unpredictable--not to mention unresponsive--animations.  For example, I could just run the code, see what the browser says the height is, and set that as the arbitrary `max-height` value.  But now say I want to add 100 lines of text to the disappearing element later.  Now every time I want to add or remove content, assuming I want perfectly smooth transitions, I have to change the CSS values.  This difficulty increases linearly (actually a little worse) if I want to have multiple elements on my page doing this.

Comment: @bowheart both great points; I didn't even think about the `transition` timing - I knew your method was superior and now I know why. Thanks for expanding on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are injecting the content is by using `display: none` - you can not `transition` that property; [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_animatable.asp) for list of properties able to have animations/transitions.

I would suggest animating a different property or approaching the dynamic content injection differently.

You can easily accomplish this with jquery if you are willing, as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qv8fLu4n/2/) or use a css helper class, as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qv8fLu4n/1/) and below.

```js
$('#injection-button').click(function(){
 $('.injected-block').toggleClass('shrink');
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%
}
body {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
}
.center-me {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

.injected-block {
    max-height: 800px;
    transition: max-height 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.shrink {
    max-height: 0px;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="center-me">
        <h1> Center me plz </h1>
        <button id="injection-button">Click me to test!</button>
        <div class="injected-block">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you suggest then? Simply creating a new DOMElement on the fly and adding it to the container div exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: you could try using helper classes like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qv8fLu4n/1/) and if you are willing to use jQuery use [sliding](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/)

Comment: Nice technique, JQuery just for toggling a class though?:P

Comment: for the css one, yeah I just used jQuery for toggling the class - you can use vanilla JS if preferred - also note the arbitrary `max-height` on `injected-block` class by default (i just used a value that would likely be greater than needed) - I actually prefer @bowheart answer over mine (grabbing height of the element you want to shrink) - if you know the height first -- I'd probably just use jQuery sliding:)

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using the `opacity` and `height` of the element rather than using the `display` which cannot be controlled by CSS transitions.

```js
// Since it isn't set in the CSS, we need to track the initialHeight of the element
var i = document.querySelector(".injected-block");
var initialHeight = window.getComputedStyle(i, null).getPropertyValue("height");

// Set defaults
i.style.opacity = 1;
i.style.height = initialHeight;

document.getElementById("injection-button").onclick = (function () {
 if (i.style.opacity != "1") {
        // Currently hidden, make it opaque and back to the inital height
        i.style.opacity = "1";
        i.style.height = initialHeight;
    } else {
        // Currently visible, make it slowly invisible and 0px high
        i.style.opacity = "0";
        i.style.height = "0px";
    }
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
}
.center-me {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
.injected-block {
    transition: height 1s linear, opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="center-me">
        <h1> Center me plz </h1>
        <button id="injection-button">Click me to test!</button>
        <div class="injected-block">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qv8fLu4n/4/

**Example with attempt at block initially invisible**

```js
// Since it isn't set in the CSS, we need to track the initialHeight of the element
var i = document.querySelector(".injected-block");
var initialHeight = window.getComputedStyle(i, null).getPropertyValue("height");

// Set defaults
i.style.left = '-9999999px';
i.style.position = 'absolute';
i.style.opacity = "0";
i.style.height = '0px';

document.getElementById("injection-button").onclick = (function () {
    if (i.style.opacity == "0") {
        // Currently hidden, make it opaque and back to the inital height
        i.style.opacity = "1";
        i.style.height = initialHeight;
        i.style.position = 'relative';
        i.style.left = '0px';
    } else {
        // Currently visible, make it slowly invisible and 0px high
        i.style.opacity = "0";
        i.style.height = "0px";
    }
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
}
.center-me {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
.injected-block {
    transition: height 1s linear, opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="center-me">
        <h1> Center me plz </h1>
        <button id="injection-button">Click me to test!</button>
        <div class="injected-block">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This technique assumes that the content is visible at first.

Comment: It is visible in the example in your question, is that not always the case?

Comment: Indeed, it is my bad. My fiddle has the inner block visible at first.

Comment: This is the best I could come up with. Technically visible but the JavaScript moves it off the page immediately. http://jsfiddle.net/qv8fLu4n/6/